# Barplot visualising check boxes

Tags: r, plot

I have to make a report of a survey where we have a question like this (all answers are checkboxes).

```
What is you favorite cake(s) (please choose more than one):
[] Tiramisù
[] Carrot Cake
[] Cupcake
```

Then the survey software exports into CSV like this:

```
"username","likes_tiramisu","likes_carrotcake","likes_cupcake"
"test01",1,1,1
"test02",0,1,1
"test03",0,1,0
"test04",0,0,1
```

I would like to make a barplot where every histogram represent the frequency of every cake.
How can I combine a table like this:

```
"likes_tiramisu"  "likes_carrotcake"  "likes_cupcake"
               1                   3                3
```

Could I just solve it with sum of all elements in each column? 
Is it conceptually valid?

Comment: `I would like to make a barplot where every histogram represent the frequency of every cake.` perhaps you meant `...where every *bin* represents frequency...`?

Comment: Yes, sorry... I meant every bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your data is in the file: `survey.csv`

Then to create a barplot use the following commands:

```
#Read in the data
d = read.table("survey.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

#Need to skip the username column, so d[,2:4]
#Use apply to calculate the totals in your table
barplot(apply(d[,2:4], 2, sum))
```

HTH

Comment: Colin, thank you for the tip!!
I have a small issue because in the columns I have also NA. Is there a command to treat NA as 0?

Comment: Ok I found it: barplot(apply(d[,2:4], 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)) I love R more and more

Comment: There is a dedicated function to sum columns - `colSums`. You can use `colSums(d[,2:4])` or `colSums(d[2:4])` and with `NA` removing `colSums(d[,2:4], na.rm=TRUE)` or `colSums(d[2:4], na.rm=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

A `ggplot2` approach would look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.melt <- melt(data, id = "username")
qplot(variable, value, data = data.melt, geom = "bar", stat = "identity")
```

Comment: I didn't know the melt command in ggplot2. Looks quite powerful! Thank you a lot for this example

Comment: melt() is actually from the reshape package, which is loaded by ggplot2.

Comment: with more recent versions of `ggplot2` you have to load `reshape` or `reshape2` explicitly rather than relying on `ggplot2` to do it automatically.